# How to get the Pipeline #XXXXXXXXX value displayed on gitlab UI inside .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

The title pretty much says it all.
I want to be able to get the value below as an environment variable in my .gitlab-ci.yml
[image: Pipeline value I wish to get]

I tried both `${CI_PIPELINE_ID}` and `${CI_PIPELINE_IID}` but in the first case I got an incremental value and in the second I got a different value from the one displayed below.

Does anyone know how to?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "incremental value"? `$CI_PIPELINE_ID` works for me.

Comment: @DV82XL it provides the same #XXXX as displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running the command `printenv` in one of your jobs. It will print out all environment variables and their values. The correct variable you're looking for is `CI_PIPELINE_ID`. Here's what I got:

```
CI_PIPELINE_ID=396845
CI_PIPELINE_IID=2726
```

- CI_PIPELINE_ID: The unique id of the current pipeline that GitLab CI uses internally
- CI_PIPELINE_IID: The unique id of the current pipeline scoped to project.

Personally, I always use `CI_PIPELINE_ID`.